# I want to store key value pair(Key and Value) into android keystore

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-keystore, android-securityexception

I followed the bellow sample 
https://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html
It worked fine till marshmallow in marshmallow it is giving some exception and I am not able to store the Key and value pair to keystore.
Bellow code I am getting exception 
For this last step there seem to be two options:

keyStore.setKeyEntry(String alias, byte[] key, Certificate[] chain);

or

keyStore.setKeyEntry(String alias, Key key, char[] password, Certificate[] chain);

I started with the second of the two, but received java.security.KeyStoreException: entries cannot be protected with passwords .... Okay, that's odd, why would there be a method that guarantees to throw an exception? Let's try door number 1.

At which point, when I call setKeyEntry, and pass keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded() as the second argument, I receive java.security.KeyStoreException: Operation not supported because key encoding is unknown from the system.

```
  byte[] encodedKey = Base64.encode("keytostore".getBytes(),
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
                SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0,
                        encodedKey.length, "AES");
                KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
                instance.load(null);
                instance.setEntry(
                        "key1",
                        new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(originalKey),
                        new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT
                                | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                                .build());
```